# What requirements do I need to fullfill to transmogrify into a legendary look?

Tags: diablo-iii

I just unlocked the mystic and had a look at the transmogrify option. As you can see in the picture below, I can transmogrify my shoulders in a list of different other looks, one of these is a legendary item.

[image: Homing pads]

How is this possible reskin unlocked? Owning the legendary once before? Or breaking the legendary into parts at the blacksmith? I would assume having the item unlocks it, but my character doesn't have these Homing Pads. And they aren't in my stash either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you **Identify** a legendary post 2.0, the appearance is unlocked in the Mystic's Transmogrification.  Any items identified **PRIOR** to the 2.0 patch will **NOT** have their looks unlocked.  To unlock them you'll have to find a new copy of the item.  Further, if you craft a legendary/set item (after the 2.0 patch) its appearance is also unlocked.

From a [blue post on the Diablo 3 forums](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/11883238299?page=2#26):

> Now, on to business. Legendary items found in patch 2.0.1 will unlock as Transmogrify options for you in the expansion. That includes the ones you identify, so feel free to do so! Once you upgrade your account to Reaper of Souls and have access to the Mystic, you should see the Legendary items you found in patch 2.0.1 as available Transmogrify options. Normally unlocking a Legendary Transmogrification option will be notified to you, but the ones found (and identified) between patch 2.0.1 and Reaper of Souls will not.
>
> I should note that legacy Legendary items (those found prior to patch 2.0.1) do not unlock Transmogrify options

Comment: This means crafted items can't ever be transmogrified into.

Comment: @strixvaria I think you unlock the transmog for crafts when you learn the plans and/or craft one.  I can transmog shoulders into seven sins which I bought from the ah a while ago

Comment: @StrixVaria I added an edit about crafted items.  The appearance for a crafted legendary/set item is unlocked upon the first craft (**not** when you learn the plan), so long as you crafted it after the 2.0 patch.

Answer (score 2):

Once you identify a Legendary item, that look is unlocked to transmogrify.

In your case, I would assume that at some point you had those shoulders.

Comment: I think I found them pre expansion on some other character IIRC.

Comment: @Arperum The Mystic, like the Blacksmith and Jeweler, are account-wide unlocks.  If you unlock a recipe, upgrade, appearance, etc on one character, it will be available to all your other characters on that account.  The item must have been found/identified after the 2.0.1 patch on one of your characters.